# Querying column data between specific times. Specifically between set hours

Tags: sql-server

I have a column of timestamps and I want to count the number of rows in the column only between certain hours of the CURRENT DATE. The date format of the data is 
May 2, 2019 2:18 PM . I need to query this data between 12:30PM and 1:30PM I can't figure out how to extract both the hour and the minute of the timestamp so it only returns rows between those times on the current day.

My column name is Outfeed_Place_Time and I've tried to look WHERE the column is BETWEEN DATEPART HOUR GETDATE and DATEPART MINUTE GET DATE and it doesn't work.

```
SELECT
COUNT(Outfeed_Place_Time) AS Parts_Hour_Parts
FROM PartData_GKN05_H
WHERE 
Outfeed_Place_Time BETWEEN ((DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) = 12) AND (DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE()) = 30)) AND ((DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) = 1) AND (DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE()) = 30))
```

I'm hoping to get a count of all rows with a timestamp between 12:30 and 1:30 but I get an error "Incorrect syntax near '='"

Comment: What's wrong with regular `<, <=, >, >=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that you are actually storing your dates as datetime instead of having a "format" which indicates varchar data.

Assuming you are storing this as dates you could do something along these lines. Note that you have to convert first to date and then back to datetime because you can't add minutes to the date datatype. Also I prefer to separate the greater than and less than instead of using between. Between can be really ugly, especially with dates. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

```
where Outfeed_Place_Time > dateadd(minute, 750, convert(datetime, convert(date, Outfeed_Place_Time))) --midnight plus 750 minutes is 12:30 pm
    AND Outfeed_Place_Time < dateadd(minute, 810, convert(datetime, convert(date, Outfeed_Place_Time))) --midnight plus 810 minutes is 1:30 pm
```

--EDIT--

To get only rows for the current day simple change up the dateadd logic.

```
where Outfeed_Place_Time > dateadd(minute, 750, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate()))) --midnight plus 750 minutes is 12:30 pm
    AND Outfeed_Place_Time < dateadd(minute, 810, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate()))) --midnight plus 810 minutes is 1:30 pm
```

Comment: I believe this code worked, however, how would I modify this so it only returns records between those times on the current day? This query will run for each new day.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Just change the dateadd to add minutes to getdate() instead of your column.